# Updating Database From Dataset?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset, dataadapter

I wanna update my database from my dataset.

```
mydataadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table0; SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table2;", con);

myda.Fill(dataset);
//......
// for example I'm doing a change like this
ds.Tables[2].Rows[1][3] = "S";

//Then updating the database
MySqlCommandBuilder com = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mydataadapter);
mydataadapter.Update(dataset, "table2");
```

then it returns this error

```
TableMapping['table2'] or DataTable 'table2' didn't find by Update.
```

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 3):

The DataAdaptor does not know about table2, only a 3rd recordset (loaded into `ds.Tables[2]`)

You need a [table mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.tablemappings.aspx) to do this.

Edit: You have an UpdateCommand, right?

Comment: I did it and no errors return. But database dosn't change. May I add executenonquery etc :S

Comment: MySqlCommandBuilder com = new MySqlCommandBuilder(mydataadapter);

isn't it do it?